# Exoplayer Subtitle

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

Hi I'm trying to add Subtitle for audio
using data of https://grepp-programmers-challenges.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/2020-flo/song.json
playing audio and setting the PlayerControlView was fine but dealing with SubtitleView got stuck
[lyric String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoeYx.png)

how can I sync and show this String through exoplayer.SubtitleView

I'm using Exoplayer ver 2.18.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a custom subtitle format, i think you should implement a custom `SubtitleDecoder`. For example you can check the implementation of [SubripDecoder](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/f72ca8338399c9e3c19e73fc0779f24baff14d35/library/extractor/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/text/subrip/SubripDecoder.java) from exoplayer.

After that, pass your subtitle decoder to the player using the custom implementation of `SubtitleDecoderFactory'.

```
class CustomRenderersFactory(context: Context) : DefaultRenderersFactory(context) {
    override fun buildTextRenderers(
        context: Context,
        output: TextOutput,
        outputLooper: Looper,
        extensionRendererMode: Int,
        out: ArrayList<Renderer>
    ) {
        out.add(TextRenderer(output, outputLooper, CustomSubtitleDecoderFactory()))
    }
}
```

Now just add a subtitle track to your `MediaItem`/`MediaSource`